# DNA longest common subsequence

Tags: python-3.x

so this is a homework question and it has baffled me a lot. I have attempted numerous times at writing this code and still nothing. The question is finding the longest common subsequence between two DNA strands and printing the sequence. Can anyone here help me and also let me know what to kind of do? I have set the window and used the find function to see where the strings are equal and then set a max function to only display the longest.

```
def main():

s1 = input("Enter first strand: ")
s2 = input("Enter second strand: ")
window = 0
if len(s1) < len(s2):
    window = len(s1)
elif len(s1) > len(s2):
    window = len(s2)
else:
    window = len(s1)
for i in range(window, 1, -1):
    for j in range(0, i, 1):
     if s1.find(s1[i:i + window]) == s2.find(s2[i:i + window]):
        max = a[0][0]
        for i in range(len(a)):
            for j in range(len(a[i]):
                if (a[i][j] > max):
                    max = a[i][j]
                    print ("Common Subsequence: ", max)
     else:
        print ("No Common Sequence Found")

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you're given strands of equal length (since this is homework, I'll let you tweak it for unequal length strands)

```
from itertools import zip_longest, chain
def longestCommonSubstring(p1, p2):

    answer = [[0.0 for _ in range(len(p2)+1)] for _ in range(len(p1)+1)]

    for r, row in enumerate(answer[1:], 1):
        for c, _ in enumerate(row[1:], 1):
            if p1[r-1] == p2[c-1]:
                answer[r][c] = answer[r-1][c-1]+1
            else:
                answer[r][c] = 0.0

    return max(chain.from_iterable(matrix))/max(len(p1), len(p2))
```

Hope this helps

**EDIT**: Implementing `find`:

```
def myFind(string, substring):
    for i in range(len(string) - len(substring)):
        if string[i] == substring[0]:
            if string[i:i+len(substring)] == substring:
                print substring, "found in", string, "at position", i
```

If you don't want to use string comparisons:

```
def myFind(string, substring):
    for i in range(len(string) - len(substring)):
        if string[i] == substring[0]:
            found = True
            for j in range(len(substring)):
                if string[i+j] != substring[j]:
                    found = False
            if found:
                print substring, "found in", string, "at position", i
```

Comment: haha I understand nothing from your code. This is an intro to programming class and so far we have covered strings and lists and the find function. He wants us to implement the find function and print out the longest common subsequence.

Comment: Alright, I'll write up a simple version of find. The rest is up to you ;]